# Laravel - Nginx, Root Directory Based on path

Tags: laravel, nginx

I have a situation where I need to serve all the requests from `https://example.com/api/v1`
from a different folder let's say `/var/www/firstversion/public` and `https://example.com/api/v2` from other folder `/var/www/secondversion/public`

Below is how my current configuration looks like

```
server {
        root /var/www/firstversion/public/;
        index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }
        location /api/v2/ {
                alias /var/www/secondversion/public/;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
              
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

The problem here is that I am getting response always from the `/var/www/firstversion/public/`. However, to verify whether the location block is being selected I tried adding `return 302 https://google.com` and it worked. So the location pattern is matching but somehow the `alias/root` isn't working. Can someone point in the right direction or what am i missing?

Comment: Besides many other reasons that won't work correctly, `location /v2/` can't be chosen to handle the `/api/v2/...` request, it is the `location /api/v2/` that would be (if being exists). Please, show your actual configuration.

Comment: @IvanShatsky sorry that was a typo missed it. Updated the config

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders/42467562#42467562)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing that you are missing is that the last `try_files` directive parameter treated as a new URI to reevaluate from the beginning. That is, after the request like `/api/v2/some/route` gets handled with your `location /api/v2/ { ... }` and there are oblivious no such a `/var/www/secondversion/public/some/route` physical file or directory on your local filesystem, an internal rewrite to `/index.php$is_args$args` takes place. After that the rewritten URI gets handled with your `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` PHP-FPM handler which inherits its root as `/var/www/firstversion/public/` from the upper configuration level.

The `try_files` directive when being used with the `alias` one has long standing [side effects](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) which I don't think to be fixed at least until the major nginx version gets changed since there are too many configurations exists adopted to those effects in some way. When you need to host some complex PHP-based system (e.g. WordPress) under some URI prefix, a workaround like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35102259/7121513) can be used, with the nested PHP handler being declared. However you case is completely different, and actually to just serve some API you don't need such a complex approach.

You should understand that you don't need to stuck with that `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` to process the PHP file via PHP-FPM daemon at all, as well as you don't need to stuck with that some kind of predefined PHP handler `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` (which I suppose is something like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65151348/7121513)). Instead, if all the requests should be handled exclusively with the `index.php` from the first or the second backend app, you are free to define your custom PHP handler in a way like the following one:

```
map $uri $api_root {
    ~^/api/v2    /var/www/secondversion/public;
    default      /var/www/firstversion/public;
}
server {
    ...
    location ^~ /api/ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        # redefine some FastCGI parameters
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $api_root;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $api_root/index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked with a bit of tweak specific to my design.

Comment: I can guess it is some kind of tweaking the `REQUEST_URI` FastCGI variable? In some environments it may be needed to tweak that one too. Anyway, I wanted to show some kind of generic approach that is possible to solve the tasks like this one.